# JS Promises: is doing `return(value)` in a `then` block the same as resolving?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following code:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(1)
}).then(value => {
  return 2
})
```

I resolve the initial promise with `1`. Then in the `then` block I do `return 2`. Does this return a promise resolved with the value 2?

Comment: yes..`Promise {<resolved>: 2}`

Comment: `.then(…)` returns a promise that will resolve with whatever the callback returns, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Calling `.then` creates a new promise, and that promise will resolve to whatever you return in the callback.

Comment: Thanks! If I `throw` an error in the `then` block, will it reject?