# JS Promises: Why does await have to be inside an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, es6-promise

Say I have the following code:

```
new Promise(res => res(1))
.then(val => console.log(val))
```

I can achieve the same thing with `async/await` like this:

```
let func = async () => {
  let val = await new Promise(res => res(1))
  console.log (val)
}
func()
```

I put the `async/await` code inside a function only because you have to be inside an async function in order to use `await`.

**What I Want To Know:** Why is this rule enforced? What would be the problem with just doing

```
let val = await new Promise(res => res(1))
console.log (val)
```

Is the reason that `await` causes the current scope to pause execution, and so forcing you to put the `async/await` code inside the special scope of an async function prevents JS from pausing the execution of all the rest of your code?

Comment: `await` causes the enclosing function to become transformed into a Promise. To avoid surprises, the language requires the enclosing function to declare that it's okay with this behavior by declaring itself `async`. The code outside of any function doesn't have an enclosing function to transform. And even if there were, nobody is going to `await` it, so the execution would never resume.

Comment: Re "`await` causes the enclosing function to become transformed into a Promise": I don't quite follow. In my example above, I thought that `val` is just set equal to a promise, and that the enclosing function doesn't return anything. In what way does it become a promise?

Comment: Do you have a twin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553862/js-promises-is-this-promise-equivalent-to-this-async-await-version)?  Part of the code example is identical.  Subject starts identically.  Questions posted very close in time. 
 Overall theme of the question is different, but very related.  Perhaps students working together?  Just curious.

Comment: Then, more twin questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510453/js-promises-is-doing-returnvalue-in-a-then-block-the-same-as-resolving) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61511457/js-promises-if-a-handler-in-a-then-block-returns-a-value-vs-returning-a-resol).  That's too much coincidence.  Just curious.

Comment: @jfriend00 Coworkers working to understand same article :)

Comment: You should advise your coworkers to upvote this question rather than making their own. It focuses community efforts into one place and avoids wasting resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `async` function is a different kind of function.  It ALWAYS returns a promise.  At the point of the first `await` that it hits, the function execution is suspended, the async function returns that promise and the caller gets the promise and keeps executing whatever code comes next.

In addition, the `async` function automatically wraps its function body in a `try/catch` so that any exceptions whether synchronous or unhandled rejected promises from an `await` are automatically caught by the `async` function and turned into a rejection of the promise they automatically return.

And, when you `return` a value from the `async` function, that return value becomes the resolved value of the promise that it returns.

> What I Want To Know: Why is this rule enforced? What would be the problem with just doing...

An `async` function has a number of behaviors that a regular function doesn't and the JS interpreter wants to know ahead of time which type of function it is so it can execute it properly with the right type of behavior.

I suppose it might have been possible for the interpreter to have discovered when compiling the function body that it contains an `await` and automatically given the surrounding function an `async` behavior, but that's not very declarative and simply adding or removing one `await` could change how the function works entirely.  Just my guess here, but the language designers decided it was much better to force an `async` function to be declared that way, rather than infer its behavior based on the contents of the function body.

The big picture here is to understand that an `async` function just works differently:

1. Always returns a promise
2. Automatically catches exceptions or rejected awaits and turns them into rejections
3. Suspends function execution upon await
4. Converts returned value into resolved value of the promise it returns
5. Chains an explicitly returned promise to the async-returned promise.

And, as such the language is clearer and more declarative if that separate behavior is spelled-out in the declaration with the `async` keyword rather than inferred from the function body.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have two clarifying questions: 1) Re "the function execution is suspended, the async function returns that promise": If I have `await new Promise(...); return new Promise(...);`, then the enclosing async function returns the second promise, and not the first. But you said the async function returns the promise from the FIRST await that it hits?

Comment: 2) Re "Chains an explicitly returned promise to the async-returned promise": I don't quite follow. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @gkeenley That `return` statement doesn't set the return value of the function. It sets the return value of the Promise that the function got transformed to. So the enclosing function returns a Promise that itself returns another Promise. And then chaining kicks in. Overall, I think this question is too broad for this site, since it seems to want a detailed explanation of promises, which isn't really what this site is set up for. Consider finding a good reference.

Comment: @gkeenley - The `async` function returns it's own promise at the point you hit the first `await`.  It's not the promise from the first await that it returns.  It's a different, manufactured promise.  The function's `async` promise will be resolved with the eventual return value from the function or rejected with the first `await` that has an unhandled rejection.

Comment: @gkeenley - If you end up returning a promise from within the `async` function, then the promise that the async function manufactured will be linked to the promise you returned and whatever value your promise resolves to is what the `async` promise will also resolve to.  That is what I meant by chaining.

Comment: Good answer. I didn’t know that the async function returns its promise the moment it hits the first ‘await’ instruction. Why doesn’t it return its promise the moment it starts running, right before its first instruction? This way, its caller function would resume execution sooner.

Comment: @PedroMachado - Because only one piece of Javascript runs at a time in nodejs and the browser so the function needs to run until it hits the `await` before it can then return.