# JS promises: is this promise equivalent to this async/await version?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, es6-promise

If I have the following code

```
new Promise(res => res(1))
.then(val => console.log(val))
```

is this equivalent to

```
let val = await new Promise(res => res(1))
console.log(val)
```

I know one difference is that I have to wrap the second one in an async function, but otherwise are they equivalent?

Comment: Does function `res` return a Promise?

Comment: @stealththeninja - res would not, res resolves the new promise ... perhaps the non ES6 version will help you uderstand what res is `new Promise(function(res) { res(1);})`

Comment: Yes, the two versions are equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Because your promise always resolves (never rejects), they are equivalent.  You could also do:

```
Promise.resolve(1).then(val => console.log(val));
```

Keep in mind that a major difference with `await` (besides it needs to be wrapped in an `async` function) is what happens when the promise rejects.  Though your example is hard-wired to resolve, not reject, lets look at what they look like with actual error handling (which you should always have):

```
new Promise(res => res(1))
   .then(val => console.log(val))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And:

```
try {
    let val = await new Promise(res => res(1));
    console.log(val);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Or, if you didn't have the try/catch, then any rejects would automatically be sent to the promise that was automatically returned by the `async` function.  This automatic propagation of errors (both synchronous exceptions and asynchronous rejections) is very useful in an `async` function.

It becomes more apparent when you have multiple asynchronous operations in series:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

async function someFunc() {
    let handle = await fsp.open("myFile.txt", "w");
    try {
         await handle.write(...);
         await handle.write(...);
    } finally {
        await handle.close().catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}

someFunc().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Here, the `async` wrapper catches errors form any of the three `await` statements and automatically returns them all to the caller.  The `finally` statement catches either of the last two errors in order to close the file handle, but lets the error continue to propagate back to the caller.